# how to invoke jbpm servicetask one by one(sequencially)

Tags: process, jboss, workflow, jbpm, bpmn

I have design below flow using jbpm

**Requirement-**

**start--->serviceTask1---Res->serviceTask2---Res-->serviceTask3--->end**

**Done-**

**start--->signalEvent--->serviceTask1-->signalEvent---Res->serviceTask2-->signalEvent---Res-->serviceTask3--->end**

I am able to achieve the same using signal event in between of each servicetask.
But i want to do the same without signal event like below

**Need to do-**

**start--->serviceTask1---Res->serviceTask2---Res-->serviceTask3--->end**

but now getting the expected output..can any body help here..

**Note:** -every service task response(**Res**)will be input for the next service task
Thanks in advance.